# Using the Modulo Operator to Determine the next Value in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, modulo

I am tasked with having to determine how much of a currency denomination can be returned as change given a transaction.

```
let change = 96.74

let cashRegister = [ 
  [ 20, 60 ],
  [ 10, 20 ],
  [ 5, 55 ],
  [ 1, 90 ],
  [ 0.25, 4.25 ],
  [ 0.1, 3.1 ],
  [ 0.05, 2.05 ],
  [ 0.01, 1.01 ] 
]
```

The cash register is comprised of subarrays, with the first value being the denomination and the second being the amount, e.g. `[20, 60]` is equal to $60 worth of $20 notes.

The final array should look like this:

```
let checkCashRegister = [
  [20, 60],
  [10, 20],
  [5, 15],
  [1, 1],
  [0.25, 0.5],
  [0.1, 0.2],
  [0.01, 0.04]
]
```

I understand in computing the logic, but am not sure how to code it. 
To start with, I would need to check if the change is divisible by the first value in the subarray. Following this, I would use the modulo operator to work out the remainder to use in the next subarray. To get the second value of the subarray, I would divide the first value of the subarray, by the change by the denomination divided by the first value of the subarray (rounded down to the nearest whole number):

```
const validDenoms = cashRegister.filter(subArr => {
  return change / subArr[0]
})

let div = cashRegister[0][0] / Math.floor(change / cashRegister[0][0])

# change % cashRegister[0][1] => Remainder

# Remainder % cashRegister[1][1] => Second Remainder

# secondRemainder % cashRegister[2][1] => and so on until all the change is given
```

I'm not sure if this is feasible using the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method or if there is an alternative way.

Please advise.

Comment: do you want to take bigger denomintions first, then you get a different result as you have presented - or take smaller denominations first ...?

Comment: Or using the fewest bills (dynamic programming/coin change problem)?

Comment: @NinaScholz In descending order, as you have stated.